# MS Flow Populate a SharePoint List from TXT File

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, mailing-list

I have a txt file, in OneDrive, with email addresses each on a newline with a header on the 1st line.
[image: txt file]

I want to populate a 1 column SharePoint list with the email addresses.

Here is my list and flow so far:
[image: sharepoint list]

[image: flow so far]

Which actions do I need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My test flow for your reference:

[image]
[image]
[image]
**Notes**:This will insert an extra '\r' into the column, which can't be seen on the page, but it will be in the actual storage.

[image]

[image]